# Navigation bar becomes the first table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have been using a navigation bar over a table view ..There are two problems I would like to address here . 
1. The table view starts from the top of the screen (irrespective of the navigation bar being added or not)
2. When I try to add this

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(44,0,0,0)
```

the table view does come down , but the navigation bar occupies the entire first table view cell and hides it .. 
 So can anypne tell me why is this happening ? and what should be done to make this proper ?
thank you in advance.

Comment: are you using Autolayout?

Comment: Like heximal said, AutoLayout is the best way to take care of the issue.

Comment: @heximal , I have checked the autolayout

Comment: @EICaptain , its already checked

Comment: In addition to El Capitan make sure top margin of table is not connected to superview but to top layout guide

Comment: @heximal , what do you mean by that ?

Comment: @Maneesh Sharma, I've made an answer

Answer (score 0):

Set proper constraints, with AutoLayout.

1. Select  tableview & navigationbar
2. then click on below right side option  with triangle shape i.e       "resolve autolayout issues" option..
3. click on it & then click "Add missing constraints" option.

It will add all missing constraints for auto-layout.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure top margin of table is not connected to superview but to top layout guide.
There are two non visible elemtents Top and Bottom layout guides. 
You should make top margin constraint of UITable to top layout guide, not to just superview.

[image]

Comment: Yes , I checked that and it's proper.. my first table view cell gets  hidden by the navigation bar

Answer (score 0):

Try to

adjust scrollview inset to no
[image]

Comment: I have checked that as well @PKT